# DataAdapter.Fill returns the row count but Rows.List is null

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataadapter

I'm really puzzled about this. I have a table in SQL Server with three `nvarchar(255)` columns and a couple rows just for testing. the following code correctly returns the column names and the row count of 2 but  `Rows.List = null`. If I use `reader.Read()` I can read the data in the rows so the query is returning the data. Any query that alters the data in the tables such as an `INSERT INTO ...` will work perfectly.

```
    DataTable results = new DataTable;
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    string connectionString = "Server=<serverName>;Database=<databaseName>;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM testTable";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
         rowsAffected = dataAdapter.Fill(results);
```

When this is done, `results.Rows.Count = 2` which is correct, and `results.Rows.List = null` which is WRONG. Why isn't there any data being returned to me?

Comment: `List` is a protected member, so not sure how you are accessing it, nor why you would. `.Rows` returns a collection, you can just do `.Rows[rowNumber]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the method [`DataRowCollection.List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.list?view=netframework-1.1) is 1.) `protected`, so you probably just see it's value in the debugger, and 2.) returns always `null` because this is the reflected implementation:

```
protected virtual ArrayList List => (ArrayList) null;
```

You have already the `DataRowCollection` in `results.Rows`, so you can either enumerate it in a `foreach` or access s `DataRow` via it's index. If you really want a `List<DataRow>` you could use:

```
List<DataRow> rowList = results.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

If you want a `DataRow[]` use `ToArray` instead.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I kept getting `Rows = {}` and I saw that the column names were in the list property so I assumed `Rows.List` should have had my data. I think I might have had a typo in my earlier work because now I am seeing  `Rows = System.Data.DataRowCollection`. I think I got myself turned around and probably had things working and didn't realize it. Sorry for the really silly question!!!